# How can I fix the wrong line spacing between footnotes?

Tags: line-spacing, footmisc

I'm writing an article and have some settings to get the desired font size and line spacing.

The main document looks right, but the footnotes are looking strange. Line spacing on the footnotes seem OK but different notes are too close to each other.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, spanish]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.54}
\usepackage{parskip}   % separación entre parrafos
\parskip=12pt
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} 
\usepackage[bottom,hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
    Hello

    One.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. }

    Two.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I force them to use a better spacing between notes, maybe the same than the line spacing, without affecting the main document?
Or maybe I should reduce the line spacing within each single note.

Comment: It's the line spacing *within* each note that's messed up.  The spacing *between* notes is the default, and is okay.

Comment: you are exaggerating the inter-line spacing within the notes with `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.54}` but leaving the spacing  between notes unchanged. Normally even if forced to double space the main document you can go back to normal spacing in footnotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `setspace` package and `\setstretch{1.5}` instead of `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=12pt
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} 
\usepackage[bottom,hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
    Hello

    One.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. }

    Two.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.}
\end{document}
```